# Acceleration of k-Means in scikit-learn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a problem that my code takes a long time for execution. I am using python for coding and scikit-learn as machine learning library. My problem is that the computation of k-Means take long time to finish (basically we have about 3000 data points for grouping in 400 clusters). This method repeats about 250 times. As for timing it takes about 40 mins to finish. Any suggestion on how to accelerate it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment on your C++ tag. How does this involve C++?

Comment: May it is written in C++ which more better than python.

Comment: Can you provide some more context info and a small reproducible example code?

Answer (score 2):

If there would be an easy speed-up for all use-cases it would have been implemented.

We don't know your data-statistics or what you exactly are doing, but you might want to tune the parameters, especially:

- parallel processing: `n_jobs` (only linear speedup; more memory)
- init-algorithm: `init`
- number of iterations: `max_iter` (linear speedup; possibly less accurate)
- number of starts: `n_init` (linear speedup; possibly less accurate)

If memory allows it, you can try: `precompute_distances` too.

But more important: even the [user-guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods) explains that your use-case is not a good fit (too many clusters).

Or try the alternative: [Mini Batch K-Means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mini-batch-kmeans).